# how to open Rstudio project using comand line

Tags: r, rstudio, rstudio-server

I'm working on a Rstudio addin, And I need to swtich to another Rstudio project.

on windows I can use `browseURL(".../project.Rproj")` but it open a new Rstudio session.
On Rstudio serveur this instruction just open the project.Rproj content file in the browser, instead of open the project.

I think that I need someting like `rstudioapi::open_project(...)`

Any idea?

Answer (score 5):

The Rstudioapi package version 0.6.9000 contains the function `openProject()`

> The openProject and initializeProject functions were added in version
>   1.1.287 of RStudio.